# How can I share logout method between components in Vue.js?

Tags: routes, vuejs2

I found this nice [mode to share a method between components in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35045119/how-can-i-share-a-method-between-components-in-vue-js)

Now my problem is this:
I want share the logout method
So i created this function into auth.ts file

```
import Router from 'vue-router';

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history'
});

export function logout() {
  router.replace('/'); // It changes url but doesnt render component :-(
  router.go(0); // It reload the application :-(
}
```

In a component i call the function in this way:

```
import { logout } from '../../utils/auth';

  exit() {
    logout();
  }
```

in template html

```
<div v-on:click="exit">
    logout
</div>
```

The app works, but i don't want reload it
I want simply change the page without reload

How to update data on a page without refreshing on the vue.js?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a Vue component to `/` route in your Vue Router configuration:

```
import HomePage from '../HomePage.vue'

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomePage
    }
  ]
});
```

Make sure that `HomePage` contains the main page of your application in order to be rendered when the router navigates to `/`.